# How to get video track's clean aperture with Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, encode

I am working on a project involving GStreamer, and I'm currently facing an issue regarding the extraction of clean aperture and encoded dimensions from a GstDiscovererVideoInfo object. I have successfully obtained the width and height using the following code:

```
g_autoptr(GstDiscovererVideoInfo) video_info = GST_DISCOVERER_VIDEO_INFO(stream_iter->data);
video_metadata[Width] = std::to_string(gst_discoverer_video_info_get_width(video_info));
video_metadata[Height] = std::to_string(gst_discoverer_video_info_get_height(video_info));
```

However, I also need to access clean aperture and encoded dimensions, similar to how it can be done in iOS using CMFormatDescription object. Despite searching through the documentation, I couldn't find any information on how to achieve this with GStreamer.

Could someone guide me on how to retrieve clean aperture and encoded dimensions from a GstDiscovererVideoInfo object? Any help or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!